# Localizing the App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm creating simple Windows Phone 8 app. I've made in **C#** *MessagePrompt* object using Coding4Fun.

```
MessagePrompt mes = new MessagePrompt();
mes.IsCancelVisible = false;
mes.Body = new TextBlock
{
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
    Text = "MY TEXT!!!!!!!!!",
    FontSize = 30.0,
    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
};
mes.Show();
```

I want text in *Body* of *MessagePrompt* be binded from *AppResources.resx*. I found how to do localizing in XAML:

```
Text = {Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Message, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}
```

but I have no idea how to use it in **C#**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the resource file directly. It should be similar to the XAML, i.e. `LocalizedResources.Message` and you might have to add the `using` reference to the namespace of that resource file.

```
    mes.Body = new TextBlock
    {
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        Text = LocalizedResources.Message, 
   //given resource file name is "LocalizedResources" and "Message" is the key
        FontSize = 30.0,
        TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
    };
```

Comment: Resources will be automatically switched depending on the Locale and if you have it or not. Even in the XAML you don't have to handle different languages manually, rather than having language specific resource files.

Comment: Visual Studio tells me: The name "LocalizedResources" does not exist in current context.

Comment: That's why I said you need to add the using and the namespace of the resource file. Please check the name of the default resource file and its namespace

Comment: I add: *using AppResources;* at the beginning earlier

Comment: I've found solution. It's should be: **Text = AppResources.Message**, and I don't need *using* reference. Thanks for help!

Comment: That means your resource file is named AppResources